# Perspective transformation with cv2.findhomography() results in wrong coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, homography

I am trying to perform perspective transformation with homography using the opencv-python package.

I have a background and foreground image and would like to perform perspective transform and stitch the foreground image on the background image given four (x, y) coordinates, as follow:

```
bgImg = cv2.imread(BACK_PATH, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
fgImg = cv2.imread(FORE_PATH, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

bgHeight, bgWidth, dpt = bgImg.shape
origImageCoords = np.array([(0, 0),
                            (0, bgHeight),
                            (bgWidth, bgHeight),
                            (bgWidth, 0)])
stitchingCoords = []

def transformPerspective():
    y0 = 285
    y1 = 400
    x0 = 447
    x1 = 600
    stitchingCoords.append((x0, y0))
    stitchingCoords.append((x0, y1))
    stitchingCoords.append((x1, y1))
    stitchingCoords.append((x1, y0))

    homography = cv2.findHomography(origImageCoords, np.array(stitchingCoords))

    dst_corners = cv2.warpPerspective(src=fgImg, M=homography[0], dsize=(bgWidth, bgHeight))

    showFinal(bgImg, dst_corners)
```

After the perspective transformation is done using `cv2.findhomography()`, I mask the foreground and background images using appropriate masks and add them together, as follow:

```
def showFinal(src1, src2):
    grayed = cv2.cvtColor(src2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, grayed = cv2.threshold(grayed, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    grayedInv = cv2.bitwise_not(grayed)

    src1final = cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src1, mask=grayedInv)
    src2final = cv2.bitwise_and(src2, src2, mask=grayed)

    finalImage = cv2.add(src1final, src2final)
    cv2.namedWindow("output", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv2.imshow("output", finalImage)
```

## Problem

The problem is the that the find result is wrong because the transformed-foreground image is not stitched inside the four coordinates that I used for finding the homography.

Could anyone guide me as to why this error is occurring?

## Expected Output

[image]

## Actual Output

[image]